# Renderizar componente VUE hasta que las props estén listas

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un componente VUE de la forma:

`<directory :prop1='prop1' :prop2='prop2'>`

Pero estoy teniendo problemas al renderizar porque necesito iterar esas listas (son datos que traigo de una api vía adiós). De qué forma podría esperar a que ambos objetos estén listos antes de renderizar el componente? Probé con:
`<directory v-if='prop.length>0>`

Pero no funciono

Comment: Revisa el [ciclo de vida](https://codingpotions.com/vue-ciclo-vida) de los componentes e inicializa las variables. La reactividad hará que, al cambiar los datos, se actualicen los valores por los que vienen en las respectivas propiedades.

Comment: El tema es que si el componente se renderizo y la prop se pasó como nula porque el back estuvo lento no me actualiza luego el valor en el componente hijo automáticamente me toca recargar cuando eso pasa

Comment: Lo que probaste debería funcionar como esperas, si nos compartes tu código completo y cómo estás iniciando las variables antes de enviarlas al componente quizás podamos encontrar el problema.